# Download but not Install Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I'm planning on upgrading to Windows 8 Pro by the end of January while it's 160 bucks cheaper, and I was wondering if it's possible to download, but not immediately install it.  If the **Upgrade Assistant** mentioned on the download page only downloads the iso image and leaves the installation to the user, that's great. However, I don't want it to accidentally install windows 8 and overwrite windows 7.  For those of you who are curious, I plan on running it through VirtualBox.

If anyone has upgraded to Windows 8, tell me exactly what this **Upgrade Assistant** does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the upgrade assistant & it allows you to download the setup files & either run Windows 8 setup right away or create the ISO file/bootable USB/leave it as it is to run the install later.

You don't have to install right away

Comment: Okay, thanks!  A bootable USB could even take the place of VirtualBox.

Comment: @CodeMonkey2 just to be clear, by bootable USB I mean bootable USB installer

Comment: @CodeMonkey2 - You're looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go.  This is a solution to bring your Windows 8 environment around with you on a usb key.